# How do I build with a custom libstd?

Tags: rust

I want to make some changes in libstd and then test them with a toy program. It looks like I can build `libstd.so` by going to `rust/src/libstd` and doing a (nightly) `cargo build`. Once I've done that, how do I get a toy program to build with that libstd instead of the regular version installed on my system?

Answer (score 2):

There are two possibilities in my mind.

**Build the compiler from source everytime**

1. Download the Rust [source](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust)
2. Make your changes to std
3. Follow the [steps](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust#building-from-source) for building from source

**Pass an option to rustc that modifies it search path**

1. Run `rustc --help`
2. The first two options (`--cfg SPEC` or `-L [KIND=]PATH`) are probably were you would point rustc to your version of the std.

I am not very sure how this would work. Ideally someone more knowledgeable could answer this part, because I think it is the preferred solution and way easier.

Comment: I did try running the version of `rustc` that comes out of `make`, but I think it kept using the system's `libstd.so` (or `libstd.rlib`?) rather than my customized libstd that also comes out of `make`. I assume `make install` would fix this, but I don't really want to circumvent my package manager (Arch Linux), and also `make` in general seems to take a really long time.

Comment: In step 3 under 'Building from source', you can pass the '-- prefix' option to './configure'. Try and pass it a prefix like '~/Desktop/Rust/' and then either add that version of rust to your path or call rustc with the full path. It still circumvents the package manager, but you can easily revert all changes by deleting '~/Desktop/Rust/'.

Comment: Thanks @adrian! I'll try that.

Comment: It did work, but the `make` build takes (what feels like) 30 minutes on my laptop, and I haven't figured out a way to shortcut that. I'm able to play with `rustc -Z print-link-args` and edit the path to the libstd that it's linking against, but when I do that the name-mangled symbols don't match up with what got built in the first part of the compile, and I still haven't figured out how to change paths around in that first part.